# Android Studio 4.0.1 release/debug build type cause R8/Proguard unworkable/workable results

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-r8

**Update: Root cause is this rule in proguard-rules.pro**

-assumenosideeffects class com.facebook.stetho.Stetho { *; }

---

- Android Studio 4.0.1
- gradle-6.1.1
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1

When I enable **minifyEnabled true** for app release buildType(signed), App hang with something wrong.

So I tried to enable **minifyEnabled true** for debug buildType(signed) just for debugging purpose, App worked well.

Again, for debugging purpose, add **debuggable true** in build.gradle for release buildType, App became workable.

1. Could anyone help for the release buildType issue?
2. If just add debuggable true in release buildType, would this app published in Play Console?

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
            //debuggable true
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
```

Comment: When `minifyEnabled true` is set you might need to configurre additional keep rules if your application (including third party libraries that you use) use reflection. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code for some background. If you think you have configured the required keep rules you can open an issue in the R8 issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938.

Comment: I did specified additional keep ruels, and this rules workable with Proguad with setting android.enableR8 = false.

Comment: I am from the R8 team. Sorry to hear that R8 is causing problems with your app. If you open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938 we can try to help identifying the issue.

Comment: OK, https://issuetracker.google.com/169308888
Thanks.